# Transit Time two hours at Chicago

Tags: usa, transit, layovers, ord

I have a valid US Visa. I will be reaching Terminal 5 of ORD Chicago Airport at 20:00 from Heathrow (London) on American Airlines. And I am having a transit time of 2 hours, and I have to board a flight of American Airlines to St.Louis at Terminal 3. Will that 2 hours of time is sufficient for customs, Immigration check and boarding the flight?

Comment: Is it all on one ticket, or do you have separate tickets+reservations for the two legs?

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm confused as to the relevancy

Comment: @CGCampbell Not much except for check in at the transit counter vs. the standard departure counter.

Comment: @CGCampbell If it's one ticket, then if the OP misses the connection due to delays then they'll just be rebooked on a later flight. If it's two different tickets, then if they missed the first they may well have to pay to rebook. That than changes what "enough" time is

Comment: Aha, not where I thought you were headed. Excellent point.

Answer (score 3):

Normally if you have a transit time this short you can ask the airline personnel to assist in expediting the matters.  However, CBP had created a page with a report of the immigration [wait times at various airports](http://awt.cbp.gov/) so you can get an idea of how long it might take you to pass through the immigration.  The max waiting time indicated for immigration was over 2 hours for July 1st and 7th with an average waiting time for the same days and times being about 30 minutes.

So it's your call.