# Immigration time at ORD

Tags: ord

I am looking at a potential ticket. I have 1 hour 55 minutes at ORD to clear customs/immigration. I am a Green Card holder but I also have a student on an F1 visa with me, coming to the US for their very first time.

I know I might have a different line so I can do most of my immigration work on the kiosks and just meet with the officer in the end but I assume a first-time visitor will have to stand in a long line. Do you all think it's enough time to do all this and reach the domestic terminal?

Comment: You can check wait times for different airports here: https://awt.cbp.gov/. Looking for the past few months, wait times for non-citizens are on the order of 20-30 minutes, but maximum wait times might be as much as 110 minutes. A lot depends on the time of the arrival and what other flights come in at the same time. Two hours seems doable though, since the high maximum times aren't that frequent. You are always welcome to use the non-US line even as a citizen so if you prefer you can wait in line with your student. You'll also need to factor in some time for rechecking bags.

Comment: Similar: [Transit Time Two Hours at Chicago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/transit-time-two-hours-at-chicago)

Comment: OT but as compassionate move I wouldn't abandon your student to enter the US by themselves even though you could get through immigration faster.  My wife was pissed at me for a long time when I did something similar to her.  However YMMV depending on the nervousness of your student.

Comment: I did not know I could stand in the non-citizen line. Yes I wouldn't obviously abandon him :)! I thought I would wait for him until he is completely done and got through. Its much better we miss the flight together than me leaving him to fend for himself on his very first time in the US.

Comment: @Giorgio Ok. Done.

Comment: Last time I entered at ORD, I seem to recall a separate line for certain visa holders, I think including F1. Every other non-citizen was first funneled through the automated kiosks.

Answer (score 4):

You can check wait times for different airports here: [awt.cbp.gov](http://awt.cbp.gov). Looking at ORD for the past few months, wait times for non-citizens are on the order of 20-30 minutes, but maximum wait times might be as much as 110 minutes. A lot depends on the time of the arrival and what other flights come in at the same time. Two hours seems doable though, since the high maximum times aren't that frequent.

You are always welcome to use the non-US line at immigration even as a citizen so it's not a problem to wait in line with your student. You'll also need to factor in some time for collecting and rechecking bags after passing through immigration.